# What do little-o's add up to?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

What is the answer of this expression of little-o's:

$$x^{3} o(\frac{1}{x^{4}}) -x^{2}o (\frac{1}{x^{4}}) +\frac{1}{2}xo(\frac{1}{x^{4}}) -x^{3}o(\frac{1}{x^{6}}) $$

as  $x \rightarrow \infty$?

I've tried and arrived at the answer $o(1/x)$ because $o(1/x^3) $ and $o(1/x^2)$ are subsets of $o(1/x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty
$.

**Edit:**
This is the problem :
[image]

When you try to expand the brackets(I'm talking only about the little-o's, because the expansion of x's terms are clear for me) in the 3rd line of the first picture, you'll get my expansion mentioned above in my post, but the answer in the second picture(see below) shows that the little o's are represented by $o(1/x^3)$ not $o(1/x)$.

[image]

**Note**: Don't mind the handwriting in the pictures.

Comment: It's indeed $o(\frac1x)$ and that's enough to conclude $\frac16$ for the limit.

Comment: Aha thanks a lot!

Comment: yes, appears to be a typo.